# Is it possible to resolve a template type under a fixed namespace?

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, decltype, typename

Given the following type:

```
struct Object {
    using NestedAlias = bool;
};

namespace Hidden {
    struct Object {
        using NestedAlias = bool;
    };
}
```

I understand it is possible for a type to be resolved from a template's namespace.

```
template <typename Type>
void legal(Type type) {
    using Alias = typename Type::NestedAlias;
}

legal(Object{});
```

However, I have not been able to resolve when the template type is on the right hand side of the resolution operator and the left hand side is a namespace.  Is it possible?

```
template <typename Type>
void illegal(Type type) {
    using Alias = Hidden::Type;
    using Alias = Hidden::decltype(Type);
    using Alias = typename Hidden::Type;
    using Alias = typename Hidden::decltype(Type);
}
```

For those wondering what the use case is:

```
template <typename Type>
void double_object_use_case(Type type) {
    Hidden::Type hidden_type;
    operation_on_both_types(type, hidden_type);
}
```

Godbolt link to play with: https://godbolt.org/z/LRNK0b

Comment: This makes no sense. Your template type is a type already, its pointless to stick a namespace to a existing type.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Why do think you need to stick a namespace there?

Comment: @tkausl (cc StoryTeller) I have updated the post with my use case.  I need to operate on both the templated type, and the exact same type name (but different object) in a specific namespace.

Comment: You want macros, the type in a template is a concrete type not a lexical.

Comment: @JonathanPan That's not *really* the use case... You can turn on and off the heating but that's not what you *actually* want - you want the room to get warm (you showed us the former, but did not say anything about the latter).

Comment: Obviously an [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...

Comment: @Aconcagua: Just want to know, if this is indeed an XY problem, does it mean that it cannot be answered in its current form?

Comment: @P.W One could realise a solution exactly mapping the question - with macros, though, not with templates, as the latter requires a feature not supported by the language. Question then is, though, if this solution is appropriate for the problem that really shall be solved with. If getting back to my heating example: "I need a fan heater - where can I buy one?" We now all tell "Go to the next DIY store!", but if user asked "It's cold in my flat, how can I get it warmer?" we would just have told "Set the thermostat higher." Now which would be the more appropriate solution?

Answer (score 1):

Template doesn't work with **name** but with type (or value).

Currently, the only way to play with names is MACRO.

An alternative is to add the hidden type as alias:

- In the class:

  ```
  namespace Hidden {
      struct Object {
          using NestedAlias = bool;
      };
  }

  struct Object {
      using NestedAlias = bool;

      using Hidden = Hidden::Object;
  };

  template <typename Type>
  void double_object_use_case(Type type) {
      typename Type::Hidden hidden_type;
      operation_on_both_types(type, hidden_type);
  }
  ```
- as traits:

  ```
  struct Object {
      using NestedAlias = bool;
  };

  namespace Hidden {
      template <typename> struct Traits;

      template <>
      Traits<Object> {
          using NestedAlias = bool;
      };
  }

  template <typename Type>
  void double_object_use_case(Type type) {
      typename Hidden::Traits<Type> hidden_type;
      operation_on_both_types(type, hidden_type);
  }
  ```